# How to use php sprintf to append positve values with "+" but ignore null values

Tags: php, mysql, null, append, printf

I have a php page displaying some data from a mysql database.  I want to prefix the positive values with "+" so I have used sprintf:

```
<?php echo sprintf ("%+4.2f",$data_row); ?>
```

The problem is that for a null value in the database the php displays +0.00

How do I get it to ignore null values and display nothing?

Thanks

Comment: i.e. with a conditional statement (if ... else or ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use

```
<? echo ($data_row<>null) ? sprintf ("%+4.2f",$data_row) : null; ?>
```